# PHPでHTMLタグ間の改行を除去する方法を教えて下さい

Tags: php, html

PHPで簡単なブログシステムを作っています。
HTMLを許可するフォームで以下のようなデータを入力した場合に、PHPで次のようにデータを変換して保存したいです(保存先はファイルかデータベースを想定しています)

要するに、普通に書いたテキストの改行は `<br>` に変換し、改行が意味を持たない箇所(`<ul>` と `<li>` の間)は詰めておきたいです。

**入力データ:**

```
あいうえお

あいうえお

<ul>
  <li>かきくけこ</li>
  <li>さしすせそ</li>
</ul>
```

**変換後のデータ:**

```
あいうえお<br><br>あいうえお<br><br><ul><li>かきくけこ</li><li>さしすせそ</li><br></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

改行を`<br>`に変換するにPHPの標準関数である[nl2br](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.nl2br.php)を利用しましょう
また改行の除去に関しては文字の置換で対応できます。[str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.str-replace.php)を利用しましょう

```
$val = "変換したい文字\nここで改行";
$val = nl2br($val);
$val = str_replace(array("\r\n", "\r", "\n"), "", $val);
```

どの改行コードが渡ってくるのかわからないので三パターンで置換しています。

ちなみに改行が意味のあるHTML構文だと改行を除去してしまうと入力した通りに出力されない可能性があります。
たとえば`<pre></pre>`なんかだと余分にbrを追加してしまったり、改行がなくなったりしてしまいます。
練習かとは思いますが、基本的にはhtmlタグを生かすテキストであれば変換せずに入力者に`<br>`を入力してもらうようにしましょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
nl2brという関数があるのですね。勉強になります。

> 練習かとは思いますが、基本的にはhtmlタグを生かすテキストであれば変換せずに入力者に<br>を入力してもらうようにしましょう。

こちらの回答を読んで気がついたのですが、ユーザにHTMLを許可するのであれば、確かに普通の改行だけ<br>に変換する特別処理は必要無いですね。
ちょっと複雑な考え方をしてしまっていました。

Answer (score 1):

最初に HTML を DOM オブジェクトに変換して、各ノードを処理して行きます。

```php
<?php

$html = <<<'HTML'
あいうえお

あいうえお

<ul>
  <li>かきくけこ</li>
  <li>さしすせそ</li>
</ul>

<p>
Hello World!
</p>
HTML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<p></p>'.$html); // dummy tag

$nodes = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body')->item(0)->childNodes;
$replaced = '';
for ($i=1;$i<$nodes->length;$i++) {
  $node = $doc->saveHTML($nodes->item($i));
  if ($nodes->item($i)->nodeName === '#text') { // text without HTML tag
      if (preg_match('/^\s*$/', $node)) // emtpy node
        continue;
      $node = preg_replace('/\h*(\r|\n|\r\n)\h*/', '<br>', $node);
  } else {
    // text enclosed by HTML tag
    $node = preg_replace('/\h*[\r\n]+\h*/', '', $node);
  }

  $replaced .= utf8_decode($node);
}

echo $replaced;

// 出力結果
あいうえお<br><br>あいうえお<br><br><ul><li>かきくけこ</li><li>さしすせそ</li></ul><p>Hello World!</p>
```

以下は、HTML 文字列の最初に HTML タグが付いていないテキストがあると `loadHTML()` による処理で p タグが自動的に付加されてしまうのを防ぐためのものです。

```
  $doc->loadHTML('<p></p>'.$html); // dummy tag
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。入力をそのまま取り扱うのではなく、DOMにして要素ごとに改行や空白を詰めて出力するのですね。else内で<pre>の場合は改行や空白を詰めない($nodeそのまま出力する)条件分岐を入れてやると、改行が意味のあるタグに対しても対応できそうですね。